# Too much recursion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript which opens new page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('a[id$="lnkHidden"]').trigger("click");    // Not sure if this is actually necessary

    $('table[id$="dataTable"]').find("tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
        $(this).find('a[id$="lnkHidden"]').trigger("click");
    });
});
```

This is the button which is called by the JS script:

```
<h:commandLink id="lnkHidden" action="#{bean.pageRedirect}" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; display:none">

</h:commandLink>
```

After I click on a table row I get this error message:

```
too much recursion [Break On This Error] ...,c=l.length;c--;)(f=l[c])&&(v[d[c]]=!(y[d[c]]=f));if(i){if(o||e){if(o){for(l=‌​[],...
```

Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: The problem is you are triggering a click event on a child which in turn triggers the parent tr's click event, causing an infinite loop.  You need to stop the propagation at some point, return false from within the click event of the a tag

Comment: Are you inserting those anchors (links) dynamically into the table? Because that would make things more difficult.

Comment: @bfavaretto no, just calling link by id. Can you provide some example how to fix this problem. The code works but with infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut the infinite loop with those changes from your original code

- add a second argument to trigger. The call becomes `.trigger("click", [ true ])`
- name arguments in the event handler : `function(event, simulated)`
- use the simulated argument which is set to true from the trigger : `simulated || $(this).find('a[id$="lnkHidden"]').trigger("click", [ true ]);`

However that event triggering and that kind of selectors are not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggering synthetic click events, you could just change the current URL directly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table[id$="dataTable"]').find("tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
        var links = $(this).find('a[id$="lnkHidden"]');
        if(links.length && links[0].href) {
            window.location.href = links[0].href;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for deleting my previous answer without warning. You reported it didn't work, and I found a serious logical problem in it, so here is an alternate solution. Hope it helps!